# Unable to install Kubernetes dashboard on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-linux, kubernetes-dashboard

[image: screenshot]I'm trying to install kubernetes dashboard on AWS Linux image but I'm getting JSON output on the browser. I have run the dashboard commands and given token but it did not work.

Comment: `dashboard commands` means you deployed dashboard? Can you check your dashboard pod running or not? and paste the logs of pod too(`kubectl logs <pod_name>`). What is the version of K8s and k8s dashboard?

Comment: how did you create the cluster? Using kops, EKS or some tutorial maybe? How can I recreate the steps?

Comment: I created using kops. I  have created the cluster on Amazon Linux AMI and  I followed  https://ramhiser.com/post/2018-05-20-setting-up-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-5-minutes/

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes 1.14+

1) Open terminal on your workstation: (standard ssh tunnel to port 8002)

$ ssh -i "aws.pem" **-L 8002:localhost:8002** ec2-user@ec2-50-50-50-50.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

2) When you are connected type:
$ kubectl proxy -p 8002

3) Open the following link with a web browser to access the dashboard endpoint: http://localhost:8002/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

Open the following link with a web browser to access the dashboard endpoint: 
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

[More info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html)

Comment: Yeah, I have run kubectl proxy command and also I followed document but I'm effecting with the same output.

Comment: can you provide  results of `kubectl get pods -o wide` and `kubectl get svc`?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with reaching the dashboard following your linked tutorial.
One way of approaching your issue is to change the type of the service to LoadBalancer:

> Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.
>   NodePort and ClusterIP services, to which the external load balancer
>   will route, are automatically created.

For that use:
`kubectl get services --all-namespaces`

`kubectl edit service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system -o yaml` 
and change the type to LoadBalancer. 
Wait till the the ELB gets spawned(takes couple of minutes) and then run 
`kubectl get services --all-namespaces` again and you will see the address of your dashboard service and you will be able to reach it under the “External Address”.

As for the tutorial you have posted it is from 2016, and it turns out something went wrong with the /ui in the address url, you can read more about it in this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2404). There is a claim that you should use /ui after authentication, but it also does not work.

For the default settings of ClusterIP you will be able to reach the dashboard on this address:
‘YOURHOSTNAME’/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login

Another option is to delete the old dashboard:

`Kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

Install the [official one](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started):

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

Run `kubectl proxy` and reach it on localhost using:
`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/overview`